# Infogram embed code not rendering in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-parsing

I have the following embed code from infogram which is not rendering on my react app.

```
code looks as below:
<div class="infogram-embed" data-id="861ca70e-552c-4a4f-960a-4c7e7ff62881" data-type="interactive" data-title="Step by Step Charts"></div><script>!function(e,t,s,i){var n="InfogramEmbeds",o=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],d=/^http:/.test(e.location)?"http:":"https:";if(/^\/{2}/.test(i)&&(i=d+i),window[n]&&window[n].initialized)window[n].process&&window[n].process();else if(!e.getElementById(s)){var r=e.createElement("script");r.async=1,r.id=s,r.src=i,o.parentNode.insertBefore(r,o)}}(document,0,"infogram-async","https://e.infogram.com/js/dist/embed-loader-min.js");</script><div style="padding:8px 0;font-family:Arial!important;font-size:13px!important;line-height:15px!important;text-align:center;border-top:1px solid #dadada;margin:0 30px"><a href="https://infogram.com/861ca70e-552c-4a4f-960a-4c7e7ff62881" style="color:#989898!important;text-decoration:none!important;" target="_blank">Step by Step Charts</a><br><a href="https://infogram.com" style="color:#989898!important;text-decoration:none!important;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Infogram</a></div>
```

I am using a html parsing library for react which works perfectly fine in all other cases.

Any idea why this is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, here is how I made it work with React
https://jsfiddle.net/wonderwhy_er/4dt28xzL/6/

Or code
In HTML

```
<script>!function(e,t,s,i){var n='InfogramEmbeds',o=e.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],d=/^http:/.test(e.location)?'http:':'https:';if(/^\/{2}/.test(i)&&(i=d+i),window[n]&&window[n].initialized)window[n].process&&window[n].process();else if(!e.getElementById(s)){var r=e.createElement('script');r.async=1,r.id=s,r.src=i,o.parentNode.insertBefore(r,o)}}(document,0,"infogram-async","https://e.infogram.com/js/dist/embed-loader-min.js");</script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

In JS

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="infogram-embed" data-id="861ca70e-552c-4a4f-960a-4c7e7ff62881" data-type="interactive" data-title="Step by Step Charts">
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

I moved script part away, it just requests a loader from Infogram and you do not need to do it inside of React render, so I just moved it to header of page or something.

You also have something else at the end of the embed which I remeved and it works. Check link.

Comment: I am doing exact thing u did, not working for me! Is it that might be possible from localhost is not working?

Comment: Hm, well I guess such embeds and frameworks that want to control how dom rendering happens such as React not always work as excpected
If you have example that does not work you could try contacting Infogram support